# Gracefully stopping ecs container

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ecs

I am having some docker container which listens on RabbitMQ and process the message received. I have a code pipeline which kicks off the rebuilding of the image and updating the tasks when there is a code commit.

My problem here is the container will be killed abruptly during the message processing is there any way where I can stop the container killing until the process is finished and allow it to stop so that a new new container will be automatically created as I am ok with the current container processing the message with the old code. My container is running python code inside.

Answer (score 25):

[ECS by default sends a SIGTERM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_StopTask.html):

> ### StopTask
>
> *Stops a running task.*
>
> When `StopTask` is called on a task, the equivalent of docker stop is
>   issued to the containers running in the task. This results in a
>   SIGTERM and a default 30-second timeout, after which SIGKILL is sent
>   and the containers are forcibly stopped. If the container handles the
>   SIGTERM gracefully and exits within 30 seconds from receiving it, no
>   SIGKILL is sent.
>
> **Note**
>
> The default 30-second timeout can be configured on the Amazon ECS
>   container agent with the ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT variable. For more
>   information, see Amazon ECS Container Agent Configuration in the
>   Amazon Elastic Container Service Developer Guide.

Knowing this, you can add a simple check in your app to catch the SIGTERM, and react appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the response so if i am able to catch SIGTERM and change the default timeout i can wait for the process to finish even it takes a longer time like max 30 min?

Comment: Worth noting that the maximum timeout is 120 seconds. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-stoptimeout

Answer (score -4):

Two ways to achieve a graceful stop in Docker:

### Using docker stop

When issuing a `docker stop` command to a container, Docker fires a `SIGTERM` signal to the process inside the container, and waits for 10 seconds before cleaning up the container.

You can specify the timeout other than 10s:

```
docker stop --time 30 <CONTAINER>
```

You need to ensure that the process handles the `SIGTERM` signal properly. Otherwise it will be rudely killed by a `SIGKILL` signal.

### Using docker kill

By default the `docker kill` command sends a `SIGKILL` signal to the process. But you can specify another signal to be used:

```
docker kill --signal SIGQUIT <CONTAINER>
```

Also ensure that the process handles the specified signal properly. Worse than `docker stop`, the `docker kill` command does not have a timeout behavior.

Comment: The question specifically requested help with Amazon ECS (https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/), ECS manages the containers for you and does not provide access to raw docker cli commands.